# How to calculate coefficients in sum by comparing?

Tags: summation

Is there a way to calculate coefficients of some grade when we have

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}(\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}) * \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} C_{n}x^{n} * \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}(\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!})$?

For example, we can calculate few terms from first and third sum, is there any way of using those terms for calculating $C_{n}$ of same grade?

Comment: The outer sums are cosine and sine, respectively. What do you mean by "same grade?"

Comment: Let assume that our sums go from m to n=7, when we write all of those three sums, we will get terms with same exponent, for example $\frac{-x^{2}}{2!}$ and $C_{2}X^{2}$. Can we use that in some way so we could calculate Cn, or am i looking to the wrong path?

Comment: As a follow to Sean Robertson's comment , we have $\cos x \sin x =(\sin 2x)/2=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^{2n+1}4^n/(2n+1)!.$